# Convergence in product topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, product-space

Let $x_1,x_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of points of the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. Show that the sequence converges to the point $x$ if and only if the sequence $\pi_\alpha (x_1), \pi_\alpha (x_2)\ldots$ converges to $\pi_\alpha (x)$ for each $\alpha$. Is this fact true for box topology instead of product topology?

But what does it mean to converge in product topology? Is it that a common neighborhood exists for all points in the sequence?

Comment: The product topology is the one generated by the sets $\prod U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha\subset X_\alpha$ is open for all $\alpha$, *and* for all but finally many indices $U_\alpha=X_\alpha$. The box topology doesn't include that last restriction (it's generated by more sets, and therefore is *finer*, hence convergence in it is more restrictive).

Comment: @RutherfordMark Where is this problem from ?

Comment: @Carpediem: I believe this from Topology by Munkres. I am not able to find the exact exercise number though. If I do come across it, I will let you know.

Comment: @Carpediem Munkres p.118, exercise 6 (in section 19 "The Product Topology"), later proved as lemma 43.3 at p.265.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373343/net-convergence-over-product-and-box-topology

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $U\subseteq X_\alpha$ be an open neighbourhood of $\pi_\alpha(x)$. 
By definition of product topology, the set $V:=\prod U_i\subseteq \prod X_i$ with $U_\alpha=U$ and $U_i=X_i$ for $i\ne \alpha$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$. Hence almost all $x_n$ are in $V$, hence almost all $\pi_\alpha(x_n)$ are in $U$. This just says that $\pi_\alpha(x_n)\to \pi_\alpha(x)$.

For the other direction suppose that $\pi_\alpha(x_n)\to \pi_\alpha(x)$ for all $\alpha$.
Let $U$ be an open neighbourgood of $x$.
Wlog. we may assume that $U$ is the product of open sets $U_\alpha$ of $X_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for almost all  $\alpha$ (as these special sets form a basis of the product topology).
Then for each $\alpha$, we have that almost all $\pi_\alpha(x_n)$ are in $U_\alpha$, that is there are $n_\alpha\in\mathbb N$ such that $\pi_\alpha(x_n)\in U_\alpha$ for all $n>n_\alpha$.
Since $U_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for almost all $\alpha$, we *can* choose $n_\alpha=0$ for almost all $\alpha$. Therefore we can consider $N=\max\{n_\alpha\mid \alpha\}=\max\{n_\alpha\mid U_\alpha=X_\alpha\}\in\mathbb N$ because we are taking the **maximum only over finitely many natural numbers**. 
Then for $n>N$ we have that $\pi_\alpha(x_n)\in U_\alpha$ and hence $x_n\in U$.
This shows that $x_n\to x$.

With box topology, the above argument fails at the bolded step.
More concretely, note under the box topology the product of infinitely many discrete two-point spaces is discrete and find an explicite counterexample from that.

Comment: In the first paragraph one may use instead that $\pi_{\alpha}$ is continuous.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I always wondered something about the way in which this result is proved in Munkres, that is also the way in which it is proved here. Shouldn't we use nets instead of sequences? (This is how Willard proves the result) I always thought that we are allowed to use sequences when the space is metrizable, but here we are dealing with the product topology in general.

Comment: Shouldn't $N$ be defined as $N = \max \{n_{\alpha} ~|~ U_{\alpha} \neq X_\alpha \}$? From my understanding, $\prod U_{\alpha}$ is open in the product topology when $U_\alpha \neq X_{\alpha}$ for finitely many $\alpha$, which is to say $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$. Am I missing something?

Comment: So the same holds if we use net at the place of sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my usual abstract-nonsense answer.

1. The product of topological spaces satisfies (or rather, is defined by) the universal property: A continuous map into the product is nothing else than a family of continuous maps into the factors.
2. A sequence in a space $X$ is a (continuous) map $\mathbb{N} \to X$, and it converges iff this map has an extension to a continuous map $\mathbb{N}^+ \to X$, where $\mathbb{N}^+ = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification, where the basic-open neighborhoods of $\infty$ are cofinite. The value at $\infty$ is the limit of the sequence.
3. From 1. we get $\hom(\mathbb{N}^+,\prod_\alpha X_\alpha) = \prod_\alpha \hom(\mathbb{N}^+,X_\alpha)$, and from 2. we see that this means that a sequence in $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ is just an $\alpha$-indexed family of sequences in the $X_\alpha$, and that a limit of this sequence is the same as the $\alpha$-indexed family of some limits of the individual sequences.