# Characterization of product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of metric spaces. I know that a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in the product space $E:=\Pi_{i\in I} E_i$ converges in $E$ iff $(\pi_i(x_n))_n$ converges in $E_i$ for all $i$ in $I$ (see [Convergence in product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524481/convergence-in-product-topology)).
Question: is the product topology completely characterized by this property? Or there could be other topologies on $E$ with this property?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the following definition:

> **Definition:**A sequence $(x_n)$ $\tau$-converges to $a$ if for every open $A\in \tau$ there is $N_A\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in A$ for all $n\geq N_A$.

So, we want to analyze the status of the following property:

> **(P)** **A sequence of elements $(x_n)_n$ $\tau$-converges to $a$ in the product space $E$ if and only if $(\pi_i(x_n))_n$ converges to $\pi_i(a)$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$.**

There are examples of intermediate topologies (i.e., topologies which are finer than the product topology but contained in the box topology) which also satisfies the property (P).

Suppose $I=\mathbb{N}$ and for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $E_i=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric topology.

Consider the topology $\tau$ on $E=\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}E_i$ whose basic open sets have the form $A=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$, where each $A_i$ is an open interval and $A_i=A_j$ for every sufficiently large $i,j$.

Note here that if $A,B$ are sets in the form above, then $A\cap B$ is either empty of has the form above.

Now, note that $\tau$ contains the product topology (as each of the basic open sets in the product topology have the required form), but the contenence is strict as for example the open $A=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} (-2,2)$ does not contain any basic open of the product topology.

This topology is also strictly contained in the box topology because, for instance, $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{-1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\right)$ belongs to the box topology but does not contain any basic set of $\tau$.

Thus, it remains to show that $\tau$ satisfy the property (P):

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that a sequence $(x_n)$ converges component-wise to an element $a$ in $E$, and let $A=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ be a basic open in $\tau$ containing $a$. Hence, there is $k_A$ such that $A_i=A_j$ for all $i,j\geq k_A$, and $\pi_i(a)\in A_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $r>0$ be small enough such that $(\pi_i(a)-r,\pi_i(a)+r)\subseteq A_i$ for all $i\leq k_A$ (this can be chosen as the intervals $A_i$ are open and we only need to take care of **finitely many** components).

Since each sequence $(\pi_i(x_n))_n$ converges to $\pi_i(a)$, there are natural numbers $t_1,\ldots,t_{k_A}$ such that $n\geq t_j$ implies $\pi_i(x_n)\in (\pi_i(a)-r,\pi_i(a)+r)$. Thus, by taking $t=\max\{t_1,\ldots,t_{k_A}\}$, we conclude that for every $n\geq t$, $(\pi_i(x_n))\in (\pi_i(a)-r,\pi_i(a)+r)\subseteq A_i$ for **every** $i\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., $x_n\in A$ for every $n\geq t$.

Therefore, $(x_n)$ $\tau$-converges to $a$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose now that $(x_n)$ $\tau$-converges to $a$, and fix a component $i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $(r,s)$ be an open interval containing $\pi_i(a)$, and consider the $\tau$-open given by $U=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ where $A_i=(r,s)$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Notice that this is an open in the topology $\tau$, and since the sequence $(x_n)$ is $\tau$-convergent, there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in U$ for every $n\geq k_U$. In particular, we have $\pi_i(x_n)\in \pi_i(U)=(r,s)$ for every $n\geq k_U$.

Thus, we have shown that $(\pi_i(x_n))_n$ converges to $\pi_i(a)$ in $E_i$, for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Are you certain this answers the question asked by the OP?

Comment: I believe the implication $(\Leftarrow)$ is false. Specifically, you only show that if $n \geqslant t$, then $\pi_i(x_n) \in A_i$ for $i \leqslant k_A$ but all other components $\pi_j(x_n)$ are unconstrained. Also, consider a sequence $x_n(i) = \sin \frac{i}{n}$. Then clearly $x_n \to 0$ component-wise but for each $n$ there are $i$ such that $x_n(i) \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Unless I have a mistake in the argument, I think I give an answer. The OP asked whether or not property (P) characterized the product topology, or if there could be other topologies satisfying the same property. I gave (or at least intended) to give an example of a topology on the product space different from the product topology that satisfies (P).

Comment: Indeed. On more careful reading, I see that you did that. As a writing suggestion (not a math suggestion!): you might want to include that as your very first sentence, something like "No, this does not uniquely characterize the topology, as I'll show by exhibiting a different topology that has that property."

Comment: @Adayah You are right, and I could not solve the issue. Basically the problem is that the boxes $A_i$ remain the same, while the elements $\pi_i(a)$ can vary inside.

Comment: @JohnHughes I guess you are right. On the other hand, in the first sentences I was describing explicitly what the question was, as I considered it was not clear if the OP was considering convergence in the product space just topologically, or assuming it was a metrizable topology.

Comment: Is there a standard name for the topology in this example?

Answer (score 0):

The (Tychonov) product topology is the initial or smallest
topology for the product that makes all the projections continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: no, the product topology is not completely characterized by this property.

To prove it, we'll abstract from the setting for a moment.

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. We say that a subset $S \subseteq X$ is **sequentially closed** if it is closed under limits of sequences, i.e. whenever a sequence $(a_n) \subseteq S$ converges to $a \in X$, we must have that $a \in S$.

Let $\tau'$ be a topology on $X$ such that each $S \subseteq X$ is closed in $\tau'$ if and only if $S$ is sequentially closed in $\tau$. It's routine to check that $\tau'$ indeed satisfies the topology axioms and also $\tau \subseteq \tau'$.

**Lemma.** For each sequence $(a_n) \subseteq X$ and element $a \in X$:

$$a_n \to a \text{ in } \tau \iff a_n \to a \text{ in } \tau'.$$

**Proof.** $(\impliedby)$ is obvious since $\tau'$ is stronger than or equal to $\tau$.

$(\implies)$ Suppose that $a_n \to a$ in $\tau$ and let $V  \in \tau'$ be a neighborhood of $a$. If there were infinitely many terms of the sequence $a_n$ outside $V$, then they would form a subsequence $(a_{n_k}) \subseteq F = X \setminus V$ of $a_n$ which would converge to $a$. But $F$ is sequentially closed, so $a \in F$, which is not true. So almost all terms of the sequence $a_n$ lie in $V$, therefore $a_n \to a$ in $\tau'$. $\ \blacksquare$

So $\tau$ and $\tau'$ have exactly the same convergent sequences and their limits. Now if there is a subset $S \subseteq X$ sequentially closed in $\tau$ but not closed, then $\tau'$ is stricly stronger than $\tau$, so convergence of sequences doesn't characterize $\tau$ completely. Hence it suffices to show that in the product topology on $\displaystyle E = \prod_{i \in I} E_i$ there might be a subset sequentially closed  but not closed.

If among $E_i$ only countably many have at least two points, then $E$ is metrizable, hence closedness and sequential closedness are the same. So suppose each $E_i$ has at least two distinct points, or equivalently, there is an open subset $\varnothing \subsetneq U_i \subsetneq E_i$.

Now let

$$S = \{ f \in E : f(i) \in U_i \text{ for at most countably many } i \in I \}.$$

- $S$ is sequentially closed.

  Let $(f_n) \subseteq S$ converge to $f \in E$ in the product topology. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set $I_n = \{ i \in I : f_n(i) \in U_i \}$ is countable. Let $J = \{ i \in I : f(i) \in U_i \}$. For $i \in J$, since $f_n(i) \to f(i) \in U_i$, there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(i) \in U_i$, thus $i \in I_n$. Therefore $\displaystyle J \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$ is countable, i.e. $f \in S$.
- $S$ is not closed; moreover, $S$ is dense in $E$.

  Choose any point $g \in E$ and its base neighborhood $\displaystyle g \in G = \bigcap_{k=1}^n \pi_{i_k}^{-1}[V_{i_k}]$, where $V_{i_k} \subseteq E_{i_k}$ are open and $\pi_i : E \to E_i$ is the natural projection. Let $s(i_k) = g(i_k)$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$ and $s(i) \notin U_i$ for the rest of $i \in I$. Then clearly $s \in S \cap G$. Also $S \neq E$ because each $U_i$ is non-empty and $I$ is uncountable; therefore $S$ is not closed.

Comment: I get that $S$ is $\tau$-sequentially closed but not $\tau$-closed in the product topology. Hence, you would like to form a new topology $\tau'$, which could be the smallest topology containing $\tau$ such that $S$ is $\tau'$-closed. I think you are still missing the proof that $\tau'$ satisfies the condition: $S$ is $\tau'$-closed iff $S$ is $\tau$-sequentially closed.

Comment: I suppose one can complete it as follows: $\tau'$ is a topology whose basis can be given as $\{U\cap (E\setminus S):U\in \mathcal{B}_{\tau_{prod}}\}\cup \{E\}$. Suppose now that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, with $f\in S^c$. Then $I'=\{i\in I:f(i)\in U_i\}$ is uncountable. Also, for every $i\in I'$, there is an integer $k_i$ such that $n\geq k_i$ implies $f_n(i)\in U_i$ (this is by pointwise convergence). Since there are only countably many possible integers and uncountably many indices $i\in I'$, there is $k$ such that $f_n(i)\in U_i$ for uncountably many $i\in I'$ and every $n\geq k$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. $\tau'$ is defined by a characterization of closed sets in $\tau'$ ($F$ is $\tau'$-closed iff $F$ is $\tau$-sequentially closed), which is a definition different than yours. Then I proceed to show that $\tau$ and $\tau'$ have the same convergent sequences and define a set $S$ such that $S^c \in \tau' \setminus \tau$, so these are two different topologies both satysfying the property that a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ if and only if it converges pointwise. Hence that property doesn't characterize $\tau$. What do you think is missing? @Wore

Comment: I simply wasn't sure if defining $\tau'$ as "the collection of complements of $\tau$-sequentially closed subsets of $E$" would provide a topology. It could be the case that $\tau$-sequentially closed sets are not closed under finite unions, but I was not sure.