# A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent in $\prod X_\alpha$ iff the projection sequence $\{\pi_\alpha(x_n)\}$ converges in $X_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation, infinite-product

Here is a proof I found. 
[image]
[image]

To prove a sequence of points converges at a point $x$, I can show that  for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for any $n \geq N$, $x_n \in U$. I don't understand why did he prove "for any subbasis set S for the product topology..."? [This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524481/convergence-in-product-topology?rq=1) makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He proved for any sub-basis set $S$ because that is enough. Let us see.
If $x \in V$, for some open set $V$, then $x \in U$ for some basic open set $U$ (because every open set is an union of basic open sets).
Now, if $x \in U$ for some basic open set $U$, then, since $U = U_1 \cap \cdots \cap U_k$ for some sub-basic sets $U_1,\ldots,U_k$, we have that $x \in U_i$, for $1 \leq i \leq k$.
If $x_n \in U_i$ whenever $n \geq N_i$ (what was proved), then $x_n \in U$ for $n \geq\max\{N_1, \ldots, N_k\}$.

(Overall the proofs using basis or sub-basis are typically shorter, but sometimes they don't give the same insight, and that was perhaps the reason for your confusion.)

Comment: I don't see why it is easier to prove in this way. I tried to write a detailed proof using this idea, but it's rather complicated because each subbasis set $U_i = \{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha): U_\alpha \text{ open in } X_\beta\}$.

Comment: Would you mind also explaining a bit about what you meant in this sentence "If $x_n \in U_i$ whenever $n\geq N_i$ (what was proved, then $x_n \in U$ for $n\geq$ max$\{N_1, ..., N_k\}$"?

Comment: I have written an "answer" which is not complete yet. Would you mind having a look and giving me some advice?

Comment: @user398843 What I mean is if $n\geq\{N_1,\ldots,N_k\}$, then $x_n\in U_1$, ..., $x_n\in U_k$ and thus $x_n\in U = U_1\cap\cdots\cap U_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for amrsa's answer. I have a better understanding now. The underline statement is actually false. A counterexample:

- $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,2\}, C= A \times B$. A subbasis for C is $\{ {(1,1),
     (1,2), (2,1)}, {(2,2)} \}$. Given a constant sequence $(1,2), (1,2),
     ....$ Since $\pi_1((1,2)) = 1$ and  $\pi_2((1,2)) =2$, we have
  $\{\pi_n((1,2))\}$ converges to $n$ for $n=1,2$. Note that $\{(2,2)\}$ is also a subbasis, but there is no $(1,2)$ in $\{(2,2)\}$. So the existence part is not true for the subbasis element $\{(2,2)\}$.

I emailed him, and he told me that the underlined statement should be changed to

- For any subbasis set $S$ for the product topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ which contains the limit there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in S$ for all $n> N$.

---

I think two proofs are essentially the same, but the proof in the picture is actually more complicated. I provide a detailed proof based on the proof on the picture. If I have any mistake, please pointing out. Thanks.

Proof: Suppose the sequence $\{\pi_\alpha(x_n)\}$ converges to $\pi_\alpha (x)$ for each $\alpha$. Let $\prod_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Hence, $\prod_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha$ is an element of the product topology of $\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$. By definition of product topology, 
$$\prod_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha = \text{"a finite intersection of subbasis elements"} = S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \cdots \cap S_k.$$ 
So, $x\in S_i$ for $1\leq i \leq k$. We need to prove that for any $i$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in S_i$ whenever $n\geq N$. By definition of subbasis, $S_i = \{\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha):U_\alpha \text{ open in } X_\alpha\}.$ ...

Comment: I think you don't have a clear understanding of what a subbasis is. It's not a subset of the topological space, but of the topology itself; so it's a family of subsets of the topological space. So your counter-example is wrong. You're right, of course, that it should be for set $S$ such that $x \in S$ and I overlooked that (important) detail (as did the author). Your counter-example seems to try to explore that, but it has its flaws that I pointed before.

Comment: Your tentative of providing a proof has also, at least, one flaw. An arbitrary open set in the product topology is not necessarily the product of open sets in the factors of the product. For a simple example, in $\mathbb R^2$ with the topology given by the Euclidean metric, the interior of the unit circle is not the product of any open sets in $\mathbb R$. What those sets provide is a basis for the topology in $\mathbb R^2$, so you're close. You just had to say "let $\prod U_{\alpha}$ be an arbitrary sub-basic neighborhood of $x$". As I pointed out in my answer, this is enough.